How can I fix the crash issue, when i combine the `flutter_gemma` and `camera` packages in my app?
I've used the flutter_gemma package in my application. And I've used a camera package.
If I open the camera and the camera is working, but if I try to capture a picture or if I do anything inside the camera screen, my app is crashing.
When I run those things separately, it's working fine, but when a put them in a same app, the app is crashing.
How can I fix this???
In this issue, I didn't even got any crash error or any other build error, it just crashing my app.
Help me to fix this issue.
Exactly, it's happening when I used these below 2 packages in a single app:

flutter_gemma
camera

My Flutter Version and Platform:

Flutter Version - Flutter 3.24.3
Platform - Android Mobile(Xiomi Poco F1)

